# NetSuite SuiteScript 2.0 Do we have any Standard ApI's for Item Master,Vendors and Customers in Netsuite

Tags: api, netsuite, suitescript

I am new to Netsuite 2.0 and SuiteScript

Can Some one help me out that , Do we have any Standard Api's in Netsuite 2.0 for Item Master,Vendors and Customers. If So please share any document related .Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Items, Vendors, and Customers are all just considered Records in NetSuite, and there are several API modules for working with Records. The SuiteScript Record schema is here: https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2019_2/script/record/salesorder.html

Here's a YouTube channel with some videos for getting started with SuiteScript: https://youtube.com/c/StoicSoftware

Here's a free Slack community of NetSuite professionals for getting help: https://netsuiteprofessionals.com/slack/

Comment: Hi Eric, Thanks for the reply. Does NetSuite have a default API that can be used to create a normal sales order

Comment: NetSuite's base integration platform is called SuiteTalk, and it has both a SOAP and a JSON API. The latter is currently in beta.

Comment: Hi Eric Thank you for the information can u suggest me that i am planning for a product design to integrate with SuiteTalk which is best whether SOAP or REST WebService JSON API and tell me that how to configure via postman and i have account id,consumer key,consumer secret,token key,token secret.